# Qt Qml, embedding a map (OSM Mapbox Mapboxgl) into a QQuickWidget C++ object, on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qml

I am developing a cross-platform mobile application which must display a geographical map. then we're using Qt framework (Qt 5.9), and the main part of the implementation is in C++.

Qt has ready-to-use Map objects available in QML. Then, the best way I found to integrate the map view is to load QML code into a QQuickWidget.

The following piece of code works fine on MacOS Desktop but I am still getting a blank view when deploying on iOS.

**map.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtLocation 5.9
import QtPositioning 5.5

Map {
    id: map
    plugin: Plugin {
        name: "mapboxgl"
        PluginParameter { name: "mapboxgl.access_token"; value: "***" }
    }

    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(60.170448, 24.942046) // Helsinki
    zoomLevel: 8

    width: 500  // no effects since it will be resized
    height: 500 // no effects since it will be resized
    gesture.enabled: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("Dimensions: ", width, height) // print 500 500 whether or not the map is displayed
    }
}
```

**viewport.cpp**

```
Viewport::Viewport(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent),
    _engine(new QQmlEngine(this)),
    _mapview(new QQuickWidget(_engine,this)),
    _toolbar(new Toolbar(this)) // subclass of QWidget
{
    _mapview->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/map.qml"));
    _mapview->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
}
```

Note :

- `map.qml` is properly declared at the root of a qt resource file, so that mobile device can access it. I know mapboxgl plugin is very new on Qt 5.9 No matter what plugin I use for the map (osm, mapbox, mapboxgl) I'm always getting a blank view on iOS, with no error message.
- When running a simple sample project, the warning message for mapboxgl plugin is something like `ssl handshake failed`. Even though Qt says the mapboxgl QML plugin, for instance, supports iOS.
- The `Viewport` class inherits from QWidget and is not associated to any ui file, both of the `_mapview` and the `_toolbar` geometries are managed by hand. For the moment there is no overlapping widgets and all of them are fully opaque. Nevertheless I tried to set/unset several OpenGL attributes (`Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES`, `Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts` etc...) but still don't do the thing ...
- Last note : replacing the map of the above code, with a simple red Rectangle with a Text on it works well.

My question what am I doing wrong ? Did I miss something in the documentation ? Nothing says iOS cannot support these map qml objects.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though this is due to a bug in Qt 5.9.0's SSL socket handling for iOS - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61053

I was seeing in the debug output "SSL handshake failed" when attempting either with osm highdpi tiles, or with mapboxgl.

I opened the online installer, added Qt 5.9.1 iOS, waited a bit while it downloaded, then reconfigured the project for 5.9.1 iOS and it worked.

Comment: I updated to Qt 5.9.1, I didn't notice if the "SSL handshake failed" message went away. Though I am able to get the map in a new plain QML application project. But not in my project where the map is embedded into a QQuickWidget.